# install rhel9 system using kickstart over http fails

Tags: linux, redhat, kickstart

I am trying to install a rhel9 system (vm) with a kickstart file.
The kickstart file was created using the anaconda-ks.cfg from a manual install of a previous rhel9 system (changed the ks file with new ip addres, hostname and the disk size).
The installation won't start.

This is the info entered in the boot option menu. I have also tried `inst.stage2=cdrom` instead of `inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=RHEL-9-1-0-BaseOS-x86_64`
[image: this is the info entered in the boot option menu]

This is the error message after starting the installer (after a short hang with the line "starting dracut initqueue hook...")
[image: error message after starting the installer, after a short hang with the line "starting dracut initqueue hook..."]

How to boot the installation from the iso loaded from the cdrom and use the kickstart file over http?

Comment: I'am also trying to do that . indeed boot cd is using dhcp. 
I'm wondering if booting off to kickstart from an official cdrom this is a supported installation .
in your .ks if you specify the cdrom command , the gui installer will  fail . by default it will download from internet.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `inst.repo=hmc` option listed at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/boot_options_for_rhel_installer/index#installation-source-boot-options_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options ? It seems like it might pass the appropriate info back to your installer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont't have DHCP activated in your desired network. This is the reason, why dracut cannot assign a ip address to fetch the kickstart file over http. Either setup a DHCP Server in the network or define a ip address manually at the cmd options

ip=ip::gateway:netmask:hostname:interface:none

Hope this works for you

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

You will need to update your iPXE (or similar template) or if you build your own kickstart file, the line which build KERNEL line, has to shown  inst.ks  instead just ks.

RHEL8 already adviced during the kickstart installation that those entries without inst. will be deprecated, it seems that for RHEL9 have been definitely deprecated.

Comment: The OP includes a screenshot using 'inst.ks=...' format and all of the other accompanying variables seem to be formatted correctly.